# User Session becomes null on page change when using Parse Javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I am making a website that uses the Javascript Parse SDK and calling `Parse.User.current()` only works some of the times causing my redirect to kick users back to the login page even though `Parse.User.logOut()` has not been called. I am using the User class and not having them login through Facebook.

Function to see if there is an active session. If there is, the page loads, otherwise the user should be redirected to the main page:

```
function checkUser(){
    var currentUser = Parse.User.current();
    if (currentUser) {
       //the page loads
    } else {
       //redirect user to the login page
       window.location = 'login-url';
    }
}
```

The above code is called in the `<head>` tag of each page:

`<script>checkUser()</script>`

When the user logs in, I check to make sure `Parse.User.current()` is not null and then redirect them to the main page. The first time they are sent to the main page, the `checkUser()` function does not find a user, and they are sent back to the login page where my `redirect()` function (below) sends them back to the main page because `Parse.User.current()` is not null when it checks it. The second time they are sent to the main page, `Parse.User.current()` has a user, so they stay on this page.

To a user logging in, the above is not a problem, since after logging in, they end up on the right page, but the real issue arises when the user tries to navigate to a different page using the tabs `<a href="new-url">name</a>`. When one of these is clicked, `checkUser()` on the new page does not find a user so the user is pushed back to the login page, where `redirect()` does find a user and sends them back to the main page where `checkUser()` finds a user as well, so they end up back on the main page again.

I do not know what the issue is, but I think it has something to do with initially changing the pages programatically because if I log in and then type the url of a different page into my address bar instead of clicking on a tab, the `checkUser()` finds a user and then I can use the tabs to switch pages without a problem. Additionally, it all occasionally works perfectly when I am using Chrome (this problem always occurs with Firefox) and then I log out and log back in and the same issue comes back.

My login code:

```
$("#login").submit(function(event){
     event.preventDefault();
     var name=$("#username").val();
     var password=$("#password").val();
     Parse.User.logIn(name, password, {
           success: function(user){
                if(Parse.User.current()){
                     window.location="main-page";
                 } else{
                      alert("no user");
                 }
           }, error: function(user, error){
                 alert("login error:" + error.message);
           } 
    });
});
```

Redirect called on the login page:

```
function redirect(){
    var currentUser = Parse.User.current();
    if (currentUser) {
         //a user is found, so they are taken to the main page
         window.location = 'main-page';
    } else {
         //the user has to log in
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem by storing the userid in a cookie instead of relying on `Parse.User.current()`. I essentially just followed the steps outlined in http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp and since the login function I was using has a callback with the object, I could easily get the user's id when they log in using `user.id`.

```
 function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
     var d = new Date();
     d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
     var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
     document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
 }

 function getCookie(cname) {
     var name = cname + "=";
     var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
     for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
         var c = ca[i];
         while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
         if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
     }
     return "";
 }

 function checkCookie() {
     var user = getCookie("userid");
     if (user != "") {
         //stay on page
     } else {
         window.location.href="login-url";
     }
 }

 function removeCookie() {
      setCookie("userid", "", -1); //setting the userid to an empty string 
      //and setting the expiration time to have passed
 }
```

On the login and signup callback, I set the cookie and then redirect to the main page

```
 setCookie('userid', user.id, 1);
 window.location.href="main-page-url";
```

On all pages that require a user to be logged in, I check the cookie by calling `checkCookie();` in the `<head>`. On the signin page, I also have a redirect so that if the user is signed in, they are redirected to the main page. This function is the same as `checkCookie()`, but I redirect when there is a user instead of when there is not one.

```
 function checkCookie() {
     var user = getCookie("userid");
     if (user != "") {
         window.location.href="main-page-url";
     }
 }
```

When the user logs out, I still call `Parse.User.logOut();` but I also call `removeCookie();` before redirecting to the log in screen.

Comment: This solution fixes the navigation issue but I wonder if you still able to do any non public class relates activities